# Getting issue while run the localhost:4502 in AEM

Tags: java, aem

```
I got a Cannot serve request to `/libn` 
  /libs/granite/core/components/login/login.jsp` issue in ` 
 localhost:4502`. Following is stack trace

    java.io.IOException: 
org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.DataStoreException: Record 
e6b6cedc11892898ce266a01a0c885120bcc3ce8b3a6f73de8ebc5f72e55efc9 does
```

not exist

```
   Cannot serve request to /libs/granite/core/content/login.html in 
      /libs/granite/core/components/login/login.jsp

       Exception: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: 
      org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.DataStoreException: Record 
       
   e6b6cedc11892898ce266a01a0c885120bcc3ce8b3a6f73de8ebc5f72e55efc9 
   does not exist
   at
```

org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.blob.BlobStoreBlob$1.read(BlobStoreBlob.java:57)
at
org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.xmlparser.XMLEncodingDetector$RewindableInputStream.read(XMLEncodingDetector.java:1108)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.xmlparser.XMLEncodingDetector.createInitialReader(XMLEncodingDetector.java:148)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.xmlparser.XMLEncodingDetector.getEncoding(XMLEncodingDetector.java:122)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.xmlparser.XMLEncodingDetector.getEncoding(XMLEncodingDetector.java:111)
at
org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.ParserController.determineSyntaxAndEncoding(ParserController.java:308)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:172)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:103)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:164)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:302)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:282)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:269)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:501)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.prepareServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:427)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:486)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:339)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:97)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:600)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:388)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:184)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:491)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:552)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:44)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:82)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:156)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:375)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:190)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.page.PageLockFilter.doFilter(PageLockFilter.java:91)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:94)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:283)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.RequestSlingFilterChain.render(RequestSlingFilterChain.java:49)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:76)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:78)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter.doFilter(TimeWarpFilter.java:109)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at com.adobe.cq.social.ugcbase.security.impl.SaferSlingPostServlet.doFilter(SaferSlingPostServlet.java:114)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:78)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:78)
at com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.servlet.ActivityRecordHandler.doFilter(ActivityRecordHandler.java:141)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.assetlinkshare.AdhocAssetShareAuthHandler.doFilter(AdhocAssetShareAuthHandler.java:434)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at com.adobe.granite.rest.impl.servlet.ApiResourceFilter.doFilter(ApiResourceFilter.java:70)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at com.adobe.granite.requests.logging.impl.RequestLoggerImpl.doFilter(RequestLoggerImpl.java:134)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at com.adobe.granite.rest.assets.impl.AssetContentDispositionFilter.doFilter(AssetContentDispositionFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.doFilter(AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.java:372)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:248)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:110)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.cors.CORSAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CORSAuthenticationFilter.java:91)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.FormsHandlingServletHelper.handleFilter(FormsHandlingServletHelper.java:226)
at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet.doFilter(FormsHandlingServlet.java:138)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter.doFilter(OptOutFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.FormsHandlingServletHelper.handleFilter(FormsHandlingServletHelper.java:226)
at com.adobe.cq.wcm.core.components.internal.servlets.CoreFormHandlingServlet.doFilter(CoreFormHandlingServlet.java:127)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter.doFilter(WCMRequestFilter.java:90)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at com.adobe.cq.history.impl.HistoryRequestFilter.doFilter(HistoryRequestFilter.java:122)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at com.adobe.cq.mcm.campaign.servlets.CampaignCopyTracker.doFilter(CampaignCopyTracker.java:100)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:87)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:81)
at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:60)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:131)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at com.adobe.granite.csrf.impl.CSRFFilter.doFilter(CSRFFilter.java:217)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ContentDispositionFilter.doFilter(ContentDispositionFilter.java:152)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:78)
at com.adobe.granite.resourceresolverhelper.impl.ResourceResolverHelperImpl.doFilter(ResourceResolverHelperImpl.java:83)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.doProcessRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:151)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:250)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:123)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:86)
at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:312)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:142)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81)
at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:131)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:142)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81)
at org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:116)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:142)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:142)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81)
at org.apache.sling.startupfilter.impl.StartupFilterImpl.doFilter(StartupFilterImpl.java:105)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:142)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.parameters.RequestParameterSupportConfigurer.doFilter(RequestParameterSupportConfigurer.java:67)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:142)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher$1.doFilter(Dispatcher.java:146)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager$2.doFilter(WhiteboardManager.java:1002)
at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:326)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.PreprocessorHandler.handle(PreprocessorHandler.java:136)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager$2.doFilter(WhiteboardManager.java:1008)
at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:97)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.PreprocessorHandler.handle(PreprocessorHandler.java:136)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager$2.doFilter(WhiteboardManager.java:1008)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager.invokePreprocessors(WhiteboardManager.java:1012)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:91)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:49)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:755)

```
   i am using jdk1.8.0_211 and i have ran the jar file ( java -jar aem-author-4502.jar )
```

This is my terminal screen-shot :

[image]

I did not get error in terminal. i tried fix the issue but not getting proper solution

Please anyone help to solve this issue. i am beginner for AEM.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and apply proper formatting. In its current state your question is likely to attract a swarm of close votes.

Comment: You might have a look at that `Record e6b6cedc11892898ce266a01a0c885120bcc3ce8b3a6f73de8ebc5f72e55efc9 does not exist` - your store might be messed up or inacessible.

Comment: what i did wrong here.

Comment: I can't tell you want went wrong and that "might be messed up" is a guess as well. Note that you not getting the error on the command line might mean that you're using different code (maybe different library versions), different "store" directories, different access permissions or that due to that "Redirecting stderr" etc. you just don't see the error. Did you check that stderr.log file?

Comment: yes i got this in stderr.log

Comment: The instance got corrupted, were you trying to configure to use Azure/AWS or any other setting? Was it shut down abruptly?

Comment: i have re-installed the AEM and run server. now i got [ HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /. Reason:  ] issue in localhost:4502.

Comment: why this 404 error in AEM?

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar issue before, and there could be multiple reasons why you are having this issue.

1. **Most Probable:** It looks like the files in your segment store/ datastore got deleted and this is causing the issue.
   *Possible Solution*: Try to find if you have your datastore files in your bin and recover/restore them. This is how they look:
   [image]
   [image]

If you cannot find these files in your bin and they have been permanently deleted, you would need to restore your instance *i.e. You would need to create a fresh instance*

If your repo gets too big try offline compaction ( It is advised to do offline compation every 2 weeks by Adobe)

Revision Cleanup Official Documentation : [here](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-65/deploying/deploying/revision-cleanup.html?lang=en#deploying)

Storage/Segment/Data store maintenance : [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/experience-manager/kb/AEM6-Maintenance-Guide.html)

2. Your JVM/JRE or Maven has been unbinded.

*Solution*:
**Java:**

- To check the Java version on Linux Ubuntu/Debian/CentOS:
- Open a terminal window.
- Run the following command: `java -version`

3. The output should display the version of the Java package installed on your system.

In the example below, OpenJDK version 11 is installed.
[image]

**Maven**:

- Enter `mvn --version` in terminal.

If you have both of these commands working properly, that means you would need to check for the deleted files.

***Before creating a new instance , make sure to clear your OS/Application cache which is generated in Libraries. ( I'm not sure where cache is stored on Linux.)***

> Datastore issues are not fixable as the blobs/files created by AEM are
> randomly generated for different data. And we cannot recreate that. I
> am afraid you might need to create a fresh instance.

Comment: I'm wondering how you can clear OS/Application cache in libraries? I checked inside there but i don't see anything related to java/aem/datastore, etc. Could you expand on what you mean by this?